# How do I edit this LINQ query for nested classes using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, class, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinedCompany { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeSkill> EmployeesSkills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSkill 
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `DbContext` class:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
public DbSet<EmployeesSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
```

Now, I can get back the data with the following:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync () 
{
    return await _context.Employees
                         .Include (p => p.EmployeeSkills)
                         .Include (p => p.Skill)
                         .ToListAsync ();
}
```

which returns something like this:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Olivia",
    "lastName": "Lu",
    "gender": "F",
    "joinedCompany": "2015-03-31T00:00:00",
    "employeeSkills": [
      {
        "employeeId": 8,
        "skillId": 3,
        "skill": {
          "skillName": "Hadoop",
          "id": 3
        },
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "employeeId": 8,
        "skillId": 4,
        "skill": {
          "skillName": "Spark",
          "id": 4
        },
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "id": 8
  }
]
```

I get really tripped up when using LINQ and I can never manage to find the right solution. I am trying to end up with the following:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Olivia",
    "lastName": "Lu",
    "gender": "F",
    "joinedCompany": "2015-03-31T00:00:00",
    "employeeSkills": [
      {
        "skillId": 3,
        "skillName": "Hadoop"
      },
      {
        "skillId": 4,
        "skillName": "Spark"
      }
    ],
    "id": 8
  }
]
```

How can I change the LINQ query as to get a result as per above?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: These aren't nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning database model Entity Types directly from your query - so of course you're going to get the full structure of `EmployeeSkill` in the `employeeSkills` collection.

You need to define a new DTO type that represents the succinct representation of an `EmployeeSkill` and materialize that in your application code after you've already loaded the data (you *can* do this directly in the Linq query using Anonymous Types, but you can't export/expose Anonymous Types (and I don't think EF Core supports value-tuples yet) so define a *proper* DTO type to void future pain.

Anyway, do this:

```
class EmployeeDto
{
    [JsonProperty( "employeeId " )]
    public int      EmployeeId    { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty( "firstName" )]
    public string   FirstName     { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty( "lastName" )]
    public string   LastName      { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty( "gender" )]
    public string   Gender        { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty( "joinedCompany" )]
    public DateTime JoinedCompany { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "employeeSkills" )]
    public List<EmployeeSkillDto> EmployeesSkills { get; set; }
}

class EmployeeSkillDto
{
    [JsonProperty( "skillId" )]
    public Int32 SkillId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "skillName" )]
    public String SkillName { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IReadOnlyList<EmployeeDto>> GetEmployeesAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default ) {

    List<Employee> list = await _context.Employees
        .Include( p => p.EmployeeSkills )
        .Include( p => p.Skill )
        .ToListAsync( cancellationToken );

    // This part below is not async because it's done in-memory:
    List<EmployeeDto> dtoList = list
        .Select( e => new EmployeeDto()
        {
            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
            FirstName = e.FirstName,
            LastName = e.LastName,
            /* etc */
            EmployeeSkills = e.EmployeeSkills
                .Select( s => new EmployeeSkillsDto()
                {
                    SkillId   = s.Skill.Id,
                    SkillName = s.Skill.Name
                } )
                .ToList()
        } )
        .ToList();

    return dtoList;
}
```

This might seem like dull, needless repetition (and I agree it is!) **but it's necessary** because a DTO and an Entity Class represent different things so you shouldn't use the same types to represent them. Fortunately there are tools to automate most of this, such as `AutoMapper` and VS extensions and T4 scripts that will generate "**scaffolded**" DTOs and other classes with the repetitive parts generated for you already.

Resources:

- AutoMapper: https://automapper.org/
- DTO Scaffolder using Roslyn: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dtogenerator.DTOGenerator
- [An article from Microsoft about the purpose of DTOs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5).

  - This article (and my answer) both demonstrate DTOs with *mutable properties* because C# makes it easy to work with mutable object properties with the its object-initialization syntax, *however ideally DTOs should be immutable*, which C# does not yet make it easy to work with ([C# 9 introduces support for immutable properties in object-initializers](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/06/16/introducing-c-9-init-only-properties/), woo - but I disagree with some of the specifics, like the introduction of a new keyword)